# Save `*Help*` buffer navigations as undo steps

Tags: undo, help-mode

The built-in help system reuses the same `*Help*` buffer for each help "page" you look at.

Help buffers have their own limited analog to undo: "back" and "forward" links in the buffer (and their underlying functions: `help-go-back` and `help-go-forward`).

However, this is weaker than the standard Emacs undo system, because it loses "forward" information. For example (assuming default help keybinds), if I do

1. `C-h k C-h v` (help for `describe-variable`),
2. `C-h k C-h f` (help for `describe-function`),
3. I use the "back" functionality once (back on help for `describe-variable`), and
4. `C-h k C-h k` (help for `describe-key`)

then I can no longer navigate to the `describe-function` help using back/forward.

Contrast this with

- Emacs' built-in buffer history functionality, which stores undos as history steps which can themselves be undone, or
- packages like `undo-tree`, which post-processes the built-in buffer history into a more intuitive structure and UI+UX.

I would like to make `*Help*` buffer navigations log themselves into the undo history for that buffer, so that I can use native undo/redo (and thus, for free, `undo-tree`) instead of the special partial reinvention of `help-go-{forward,back}`.

What's a good way to do that?

(My first thought was wrapping or advising the relevant functions to add entries to `buffer-undo-list` (probably of the form `(apply FUNCTION-NAME . ARGUMENTS`, see `buffer-undo-list` docs)), but I noticed that the functions which create help pages like `describe-variable` also set `buffer-undo-list` to `t`, so something more invasive would be required.)

Comment: My suggestion, if you really want this: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. That's for enhancement requests, as well as bugs.

Comment: @Drew, thanks, but alas, I feel huge priority for making *my* UX/UI exactly how I want it, and low priority on the inherently less reliable, probably slower, somewhat tedious, and frequently viscerally unpleasant to me process of conveying to others what I want and why it's good to have and then waiting for it to roll into a release. Even if I did all that, I would then still want a solution in my current installed official release Emacs instances. I have also found that often the best way to get a feature or fix to happen upstream starts with me just implementing it myself anyway.

Comment: For others with similar wants to mine, I've moved on to an even better (for me) solution: I put advice around the function `help-buffer` to use a distinct buffer name for each help page. Couple examples: `*Help (function: help-buffer)*`, `*Help (variable: undo-limit)*.` This lets me keep multiple help pages open for reference at once, and buffer switching with narrowing search is even better than a history tree for revisiting help pages.